# getServletContext().getRealPath("/") in public class Send_Message implements Job {

Tags: servlets

norming, I'm english is not well, itry to do my best.new in developer in java web.

I've

```
public class Send_Message implements Job {  
   public void createPdf(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  {
      String pathreport2 = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"report\\rpt_message.jasper";
   }
```

but I've error

---

i've this message **servletContext cannot be resolved** concern **servletContext**

Answer (score -1):

You can use it following way:
String absolutePathToIndexJSP = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "index.jsp";

Comment: i've this message servletContext cannot be resolved concern servletContext